# Putting together regex to highlight words inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hey all I am trying to have a simple way of adding multiple item names to a **regex** list:

```
var whatToLookFor = "DOZ,DOB".split(",");
var highlightThis = "";

$.each(whatToLookFor,function(i){
   highlightThis += whatToLookFor[i] + "\/|";
});

highlightThis = "\/" + highlightThis.replace(/.$/,"\/gi");

console.log(highlightThis);

/DOZ\/|DOB\//gi <-highlightThis should look like this

$('.string-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: highlightThis
});
```

However, I am not getting the same values shown on the page using **highlightThis** as I do when using the **/DOZ/|DOB//gi**. I output the value of **highlightThis** and it looks just like it should but still does not work for some reason.

```
$('.string-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: /DOZ\/|DOB\//gi
});
```

What could I be missing in order for it to treat it like a **regex** value? It's probably something simple that I am just overlooking. :o)

The code I am using is [here](https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/)

**final working code**

```
var whatToLookFor = "DOZ,DOB".split(",");
var highlightThis = "";

$.each(whatToLookFor,function(i){
    highlightThis += whatToLookFor[i] + "/|";
});

highlightThis = highlightThis.replace(/.$/,"");

$('.string-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: new RegExp(highlightThis, 'gi')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is you're creating it as a string vs as a regex. Instead of adding on `gi` at the end, use new RegExp and pass your string in and then your flags:

```
new RegExp('DOZ\\/|DOB/', 'gi');
```

This will output what you're expecting:

```
/DOZ\/|DOB//gi
```

Comment: How would that work in the csv?

Comment: Not sure I understand, modify your javascript code you pasted above.

Comment: The whatToLookFor has CVS that I split and in the loop is where I was trying to put it all together before passing it over to highlightThis

Comment: This would go after your loop.

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks Matt!